# SliderExtender with BehaviorID is not rendered after pageLoad(), but work after postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I'm using a asp.net slider inside an **UpdatePanel** within a **page control**.

I assign a behaviorID and call it using `$find(behaviorID)` in both `$(document).ready` and  `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest`functions inside a JavaScript located in the **bottom** of the page.

The JavaScript function on the slider doesn't work after page_initial. 
It fails to find the slider in JavaScript, i.e. `$find(behaviorID) = null`. while other JavaScript functions set in the `$(document).ready` does work.
However, I can view slider's rail and drag it.

But when I do any postback on the page with other controls , the slider works smoothly!
It generate additional tags with  `<... Class= ...Behavior_ID>`

and the JS which is used to generate Slider and its Event in source code looks like:

```
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(AjaxControlToolkit.SliderBehavior, {"Length":410,"Maximum":100,"Minimum":-100,"TooltipText":"Adjust Target","id":"targetSlider_JS"}, null, null, $get("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder3_Target1_txtSlider"));
});
```

The page is in 'content' of a MasterPage.
I guess it doesn't render the slider correctly when page-init, need some server side setting for slider?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

didn't find solution.

used jquery slider instead.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem that was intermittent. Sometime it was null and other times was fine. I added a small setTimeout of 100ms to delay a call to $find and it works now.